# How to add list of objects to Combox C#

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a list of objects of Person class with what I need to add items to a combobox. What I need to do is display the Person Names in the combobox but when selected from the dropdown, call a function passing the Person ID.

Now i have to retrieve the the Person ID using the selected Person Name again from the DB. I would like to know if there is easier way to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you post the code you have tried so far?

Comment: Also, please indicate the technology you use (WinForms or WPF or WebForms or..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        List<Person> personList = new List<Person>();
        personList.Add(new Person() {Name =  "Name1", Id=1 });
        personList.Add(new Person() { Name = "Name2", Id=2 });
        personList.Add(new Person() { Name = "Name3", Id=3 });
        personList.Add(new Person() { Name = "Name4", Id=4 });
        personList.Add(new Person() { Name = "Name5", Id=5 });

        comboBox1.DataSource = personList;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
```